# Issue when rendering a torus in webGL

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, opengl-es, webgl

I'm writing a program that is supposed to draw 3D parametric shapes in webgl. The code I have currently seems to work (mostly) for a sphere, but when I switch out the equations used to find x, y, and z, for a torus, only the top half of the torus is being rendered (in the x-y plane). All of the parametric equations I have (for a sphere, a torus, and a cylinder) work when just the 2d canvas context is used without any webgl; however, when webgl is used, there seems to be a problem. In addition the problem with only rendering half of the torus, the equation used to render the cylinder doesn't render anything.

What could be causing only half of the torus to be rendered? The code for rendering the parametric shapes is below:

```
            var latitudeBands = 30;
            var longitudeBands = 30;
            var radius = 0.5;

            var vertexPositionData = [];
            var normalData = [];
            var textureCoordData = [];
            var indexData = [];

            for (var latNumber = 0; latNumber <= latitudeBands; latNumber++)                     
              {  var theta = latNumber * Math.PI / latitudeBands;
                var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
                var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

                for (var longNumber = 0; longNumber <= longitudeBands; longNumber++) {
                    var phi = longNumber * 2 * Math.PI / longitudeBands;
                    var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
                    var cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);

                    //Equation used for sphere     
                    //var x =  Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
                    //var y = Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
                    //var z = Math.sin(phi);

                    //Equation used for torus
                    var x = (1 + radius * Math.cos(phi)) * Math.cos(theta);
                    var y = (1 + radius * Math.cos(phi)) * Math.sin(theta);
                    var z = radius * Math.sin(phi);

                  //Equation used for cylinder
                  //var x =  Math.cos(theta);
                  //var y = Math.sin(theta);
                  //var z = 2 * latNumber - 1;


                    var u = 1 - (longNumber / longitudeBands);
                    var v = 1 - (latNumber / latitudeBands);

                    normalData.push(x);
                    normalData.push(y);
                    normalData.push(z);
                    textureCoordData.push(u);
                    textureCoordData.push(v);
                    vertexPositionData.push(radius * x);
                    vertexPositionData.push(radius * y);
                    vertexPositionData.push(radius * z)
                }
            }

            for (var latNumber = 0; latNumber < latitudeBands; latNumber++) {
                for (var longNumber = 0; longNumber < longitudeBands; longNumber++) {
                    var first = (latNumber * (longitudeBands + 1)) + longNumber;
                    var second = first + longitudeBands + 1;
                    indexData.push(first);
                    indexData.push(second);
                    indexData.push(first + 1);
                    indexData.push(second);
                    indexData.push(second + 1);
                    indexData.push(first + 1);
                }
            }

        moonVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexPositionData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        moonVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        moonVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = vertexPositionData.length / 3;

        moonVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexIndexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        moonVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
        moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = indexData.length;
```

Comment: The normals of a torus need to be calculated not from the center, like the sphere where the normal is the same as the x,y,z coord. You would be best of calculating the normals after you have created the faces. The normal for each vert is the mean of the normals of all faces using that vert. The normal is used to cull backfacing faces.  Setting the material to doublesided will most likely show all faces but your shading will not be correct with the wrong normals.

Comment: @Blindman67 I thought the normals are only needed whenever you are using lighting? I'm not using any in this case so I'm not sure if the calculation of the normals would affect the rendering. I just updated the code with the arrays that I'm sending to the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elevation angle range for a sphere is only PI (from pole to pole), but
the range is 2*PI for a torus; Thus

```
theta = latNumber * Math.PI / latitudeBands
```

should be

```
theta = latNumber * 2 * Math.PI / latitudeBands
```

See [WebGL Torus Example](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs442/lectures/texture/torus/class/webgl-torus-mesh/torus.html).

Comment: That was exactly the error, thanks! Do you know what the best web resource would be for learning how to draw advanced shapes in WebGL?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly for these type of problems the most likely error arise from the geometry generation code. I suggest consult the excellent THREE.js source code to check for discrepancies. Toros generation code [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/TorusGeometry.js).

You can find code for other geometry generation [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/extras/geometries) should you need them in the future.